# Помогите правильно организовать запрос SQL

Tags: sql

Помогите правильно организовать запрос SQL

```
 $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `manufacturer` SET
              `manufacturer_id` ='$val[vendorID]',
              `name`='$val[name]'";
        db_query($sqlstr);
```

в значениях массива $val[name] попадаются названия которые содержат знак '   вот пример  Daddy's Big Top

что нужно сделать что бы такой запрос обработался когда в слове попадается такой символ?

Comment: К сожалению, с телефона не имею возможности ответить развёрнуто, напишу коротко в комментарии. Вам должна помочь функция mysql_real_escape_string(). Почитайте про неё, очень полезная вещь. Вот здесь есть про неё и про защиту запросов к базе в целом: http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/slashes

Comment: Если одинарная кавычка - единственный потенциально проблемный символ, то просто удвойте его тупым REPLACE (или что там в PHP для этого дела имеется).

Comment: почему идут пустые значения не подскажите?       $test = $val['name'] ;
  $test1 = mysql_real_escape_string($test1);



        $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `manufacturer` SET
              `manufacturer_id` ='$val[vendorID]',
     `name`='$test1'";
        db_query($sqlstr);

Answer (score 1):

в итоге это получилось сделать так

```
$test = addcslashes($val['name'] , "'" );
$sqlstr = "INSERT INTO `manufacturer` SET `manufacturer_id` ='$val[vendorID]',`name`='$test'";
```